# How to use stored certificate in Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a stored certificate in Jenkins, and I need to use it in a pipelinebuild job, but the problem is it appears the Pipeline can't use certificates:

trying to use:

```
    environment {
        KEY = credentials('mycert')
    }
```

results in:

```
ERROR: No suitable binding handler could be found for type com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.CertificateCredentialsImpl. Supported types are StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials,FileCredentials,StringCredentials,SSHUserPrivateKey.
```

How do I get around this and use that stored cert in a pipeline? There has to be a way otherwise why would storing certs as credentials even be possible.. would be useless to store something without ever being able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Some credential types cannot be bound directly in an environment section. [From the docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials) :

> If you need to set credentials in a Pipeline for anything other than secret text, usernames and passwords, or secret files - i.e SSH keys or certificates, then use Jenkins' Snippet Generator feature, which you can access through Jenkins' classic UI.

So the generator would give you something looking like this:

```
withCredentials([certificate(aliasVariable: '', credentialsId: 'myCert', keystoreVariable: 'CERT', passwordVariable: '')]) {
    // some block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually set the credential NAME into an environment variable

```
environment {
    CERT = 'mycert'
}
```

Then I can use that name where ever I need it

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "${env.CERT}",
                                  passwordVariable: 'CERT_PASSWORD',
                                  usernameVariable: 'CERT_USER')]) {
    // Do things needing environment variables
}
```

or

```
checkout(poll: false,
         scm: [
               $class: 'GitSCM',
               userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "${env.CERT}", 
                                   url: 'https://code.example.org/somerepo']]
               ])
```